# How to run 8 million rows of data with `Parallel::mclapply` efficiently?

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I attempted to split a character vector of about 8 millions elements using the following code

```
library(parallel)
detectCores()

s <- system.time({
    sepTime <- mclapply(orders_largest1stGroup$Time, function(x) x %>% strsplit(split = " ") %>% unlist() %>% strsplit(split = ":") %>% unlist(), mc.cores = 2) 
})

sepTime %>% unlist() %>% matrix(ncol=4, byrow=T) %>% as.data.frame()
```

The vector `orders_largest1stGroup$Time` is like the following

```
"2016-01-01 13:37:23", "2016-01-02 16:37:23", "2016-01-03 12:37:23"
```

However, more than 15 minutes past, it is still running. So, I wonder something must be not right about my code or my approach of doing it.

Could anyone have a look and tell me how to run this code fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient solution to split this 8million rows data.frame:
largeData$Time is a vector of strings like

```
"2016-01-01 13:37:23", "2016-01-02 16:37:23", "2016-01-03 12:37:23"
```

To split them within 30 seconds, do this instead of `for` loop:

```
largeData %>% mutate(Date=Time %>% substr(1,10) %>% as.Date(), Hour=Time %>% substr(12,13) %>% as.numeric(), Minute=Time %>% substr(15,16) %>% as.numeric())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a lot more efficient that apply method.

```
dat <- c("2016-01-01 13:37:23", "2016-01-02 16:37:23", "2016-01-03 12:37:23")
dat <- strptime(dat, format="%F %X") 
date <- format(dat, "%F")
hour <- format(dat, "%H")
minute <- format(dat, "%M")
seconds <- format(dat, "%S")
```

If you are interested to optimise the process, perhaps you could split your data into different subset and adjust each set separately with mclapply or equivalent.

Comment: you are right, subset into several small groups, help me tolerate the waiting time. Thanks